# Bitmap.CreateBitmap exception - Out Of Memory

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, out-of-memory, xamarin.forms

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        LoadApplication (new App ());
        if (bitmapChart != null && !bitmapChart.IsRecycled)
        {
            bitmapChart.Recycle();
        }
        bitmapChart = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap (2000, 800, Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);            
    }

public volatile Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmapChart;
```

I want to create volatile Bitmap.
When I open my application 3rd time, I have exception:  Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError.

If I use static Bitmap instead of volatile Bitmap, application works correctly and I can open it many times.

Why I can't use volatile Bitmap?

Comment: 2000x800??? I believe it ..first of all increase the heap size , and after trying to force the garbage collector after you have created the bitmap

Comment: I want to show wide chart. Do you have better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should set a larger `Java Heap size`. Go to you Android project options -> Advanced and set `Java Heap size` to 1G or 2G.
- Set `android:largeHeap` to `true` in the Android application manifest

> android:largeHeap Whether your application's processes should be
>   created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes
>   created for the application. It only applies to the first application
>   loaded into a process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow
>   multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option
>   consistently or they will have unpredictable results. Most apps should
>   not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall
>   memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not
>   guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices
>   are constrained by their total available memory.
>
> To query the available memory size at runtime, use the methods
>   getMemoryClass() or getLargeMemoryClass().

Comment: Thank you. I'll try. I want to display wide chart. Do you have a better idea? What I must use instead of bitmap for draw large chart?

Comment: Large bitmap isn't a good option for that purpose. You could try combine Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView which contains single View, then draw on in with NControl(https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl) library.  It would be a cross platform solution. For platform specific solutions use renderers: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/ and draw manually (platform specific). Please also note that there is a lot of chart components which support Xamarin.Forms and chart scrolling already.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the information was useful, please mark it as a correct answer. Thanks.